# How can I calculate the maximum number of rows in a textarea with a set height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I'm currently developing a sort of browser based word processor and am using a textarea to hold the contents. The textarea has a height set to 100% to fill a container div with padding and other elements in it. Is there a way I can calculate the number of rows that will fit in the textarea without overflowing so I can prevent additional lines from being created? I could of course just hide the overflow, but I don't want that excess text to get saved when I push the contents to a database.

Comment: How about restricting the length of text in your text box as most textarea do (example, stackoverflow comment) so that you are sure the length cannot exceed what you set.

Comment: You're referring to the maxlength attribute for textareas? The number of characters I want to allow would also depend on how many of those were new line characters. If a textarea only had one character per line then the maxlength would be much smaller than if there were no newlines at all and everything just wrapped like normal.